# How to break a loop in mikroC

Tags: c, loops, break

I am primary in programming with mikroC (Microchip). I need to break a loop in my code but I have no result with "break;" if you could help me?
I need to make after while condition is satisfied "stop" everything!

This is my flowchart for my project:

[image: My project flow chart "AGS System" Auto Generator Starter]

Here is my code:

```
void main() {
    int x=0;
    TRISD=0B00011111;
    TRISB=0B11111000;
    PORTB.F0=0;
    PORTB.F1=0;
    PORTB.F2=0;
    while(1){
        if(x==3){break;}
        if(PORTD.F1==0)
        {
            if(PORTB.F2==0){PORTB.F1=1;delay_ms(50);PORTB.F0=1;delay_ms(300);PORTB.F2=1;}
        }
        if(PORTB.F2==1){PORTB.F0=0;}
        if(PORTD.F1==1)
        {
            PORTB.F1=0;PORTB.F0=0;PORTB.F2=0;
        }
        PORTB.F2=0;
        delay_ms(300);
        while(x<=4){
            x++;
            if(PORTD.F1==0)
            {
                if(PORTB.F2==0){PORTB.F1=1;delay_ms(50);PORTB.F0=1;delay_ms(300);PORTB.F2=1;}
            }
            if(PORTB.F2==1){PORTB.F0=0;}
            if(PORTD.F1==1){delay_ms(300);PORTB.F0=0;PORTB.F1=0;PORTB.F2=0;}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second while loop starts with`x = 0`, and exits when `x = 5` (when `x <= 4` gets false), so your `if(x==3){break;}` is never triggered.

Comment: So how i can slove this?

Comment: I would suggest formatting your code better... If you want one-liners, then write a function with appropriate arguments, and call that, instead of cramming multiple statements in one line.

Comment: Certainly i'll do but first to get right code

Comment: Now, break working to make 'PORTB.F1' and 'PORTB.F2' still HIGH!

Comment: @MahdiAlzubaidi But that's doing it exactly backwards :). The purpose of having well formatted code is to make it easier to "get right code". There's no point in formatting code you aren't ever going to look at again (to debug or to understand what the program does). When you first have an issue with some code, that's the time to get things like formatting code in order, and doubly so if you are going to show the code to somebody else, who needs to understand it to help you.

Comment: Great, could you help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
if(x>=3){break;}
```

since you increase x to 5 here: `while(x<=4){x++`, and you enter an infinite loop.

Comment: All right, but let me know exactly where will be this condition , because in it's currently place didn't work.

Comment: @MahdiAlzubaidi The flow must be stuck somewhere.

Comment: This is actually the right answer. your X overflows and you keep running

Comment: You exit the second loop when `x = 5`, then you go back to the start of the first loop, test if `x==3` (which is false), and continue again forever because you will never modify `x` again.

Comment: As i said i'm primary please tell me what to do exactly?

Comment: Ah @this said, change you `if(x==3)̀` test to `if(x >= 3)`.

Comment: I have tested this if(x>=3) but still continue "Just second loop break" i need to break everything

Comment: Or, you can also completely remove your `while(1)` loop and just put the code inside the main, as your design will only run this code once: You will always increment `x`, and your `break` should always trigger on the second run (if you fix the test, obviously)

Comment: the previous testing breaking the second while loop inspite of i want to break everything

Comment: Did you change the test at line 9 of your sample, or did you add a new test ?

Comment: @NiBZ actually i need to repeat this design every time not once but when (x<=4) exhausted breaks everything

Comment: @NiBZ i changed it from (x==3) to (x>=3)